# PHP Warning: include_once() Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Tags: php

I know this error is very common, I've tried to search google, I did the tricks to no avail. 
So my setup is, I have 3 directories:

**CLASSES**->constants 
**PAGES** 
**INITCONTROLS**

**EDIT:** 
I've got new error:

***Warning: require_once(initcontrols/config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in***

below is my fragment of code:

```
require_once("initcontrols/config.php");

<div>
<?php 
$file = "initcontrols/header_myworks.php"; 
include_once($file); 
echo $plHeader;?>   
</div>
```

What is still lacking in here? Thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the file you're trying to include is in the include path ? Or that the calling file is in the root directory ?

Comment: @betty - you can't include the file which is in parent directory of `www` if you are trying so

Comment: Try `include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file); `

Comment: @BogdanBurim when i changed my include_once, the new problem goes to my require_once. I've updated my post.

Comment: @BogdanBurim I realized recently through Google Analytics that my analytics file wasn't being pulled through require_once and the directory path.  I did not completely use your path suggestion but the 'include_once' did the trick for me. Example include_once(content/analyticstracking.php).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work if current file is located in same directory where **initcontrols** is:

```
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$base_dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)  . $ds . '..') . $ds;
require_once("{$base_dir}initcontrols{$ds}config.php");
?>
<div>
<?php 
$file = "{$base_dir}initcontrols{$ds}header_myworks.php"; 
include_once($file); 
echo $plHeader;?>   
</div>
```

Comment: oh my bad! they are not in the same directory, how could I change it?

Comment: My config.php is in initcontrols folder, whilst my php file is in pages folder

Comment: it's giving me this: Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\metro\pages\../initcontrols/header_myworks.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: Is `header_myworks.php` located in the `C:\xampp\htdocs\metro\initcontrols\` ?

Comment: To clarify things, under my root directory, there are 3 sub directories, namely: pages, classes, initcontrols. in my initcontrols contains header_myworks.php and config.php, whilst in pages folder contains mypages.php

Comment: Strange.. This `C:\xampp\htdocs\metro\pages\../initcontrols/header_myworks.php` is equal to `C:\xampp\htdocs\metro\initcontrols/header_myworks.php`. Is the second path right? Try updated code and tell me waht it will show.

Comment: It's giving this: Warning: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\metro\pages\../initcontrols/header_myworks.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\metro\pages\myworks.php on line 23

Answer (score 3):

The include path is set against the server configuration ([PHP.ini](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-set-php-include-path-in-php-ini-file/)) but the include path you specify is relative to that path so in your case the include path is (actual path in windows):

```
C:\xampp\php\PEAR\initcontrols\header_myworks.php
```

providing the path you pasted in the subject is correct. Make sure your file is located there.

For more info you can [get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php) and [set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) the include path programmatically.

Comment: @NullPointer - I'm not sure what you mean. This isn't the path he should use to include the file, this is the path PHP is expecting the file to be in.

Comment: so what do I do to my file? include it in PEAR folder?

Comment: Well, it depends. If it doesn't matter where the file is then just put `header_myworks.php` in the directory in my post. If you want actual structure to your app (which is the best option) you can change your Include path to avoid messing about code later on.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you use a relative path.

The easy way to fix this is by using the `__DIR__` magic constant, like:

```
require_once(__DIR__."/initcontrols/config.php");
```

From the PHP doc:

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of
>   the included file is returned

Answer (score 0):

Put in config.php this

```
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Whether this is correct or not is up to the OP. However, a short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.